# How to deal with 4 bit 7 segment display drivers making a decimal counter?

Tags: hex, driver, counter, ttl, bcd

I need to make a 7 digit TTL pulse counter. Lets not focus on the details, but my exact problem is how to deal with the hex to decimal conversion in 7 segment display drivers. Every 7 sd drivers IC that I find is a 4 bit one, which means it will count 0-F or 0-9 ant then goes blank or whatever. I managed to find an algorithm to cascade the counter IC's to get my numbering right, but how do I make the 7 sd to come back to 0 after digit 9? Are there any resettable 0-9-5 type like 7sds? I feel like I am missing something important here, what is usual solution in such case?